# Why akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool is deprecated in Akka 2.0.2?

Tags: scala, akka, fork-join, jsr166

Is it mean that it will move to Scala 2.10 or jsr166y will be released separately? ...or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the new implementation of ForkJoin will be embedded in Scala 2.10 and Akka will use that.